# Auto Select the Multiselect 2's values based on Multiselect 1 values

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my view page, I have two multiselects named multiselect1, multiselect2 . In multiselect1, Iam fetching values from database and making them selected dynamically. Based on that, the values in Multiselect1 should be selected in multiselect2 automatically

```
 <h4>First Multiselect</h4>
  <select id='multipleSelect1' multiple='multiple' style="margin-right:40px">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<h4> Second Multiselect </h4>

  <select id='multipleSelect2' multiple='multiple'>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
  </select>
```

JSFiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/jaLygLzo/10/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough..
Just remove the `For` loop..

```
$("#multipleSelect2").val(selected_values);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/jaLygLzo/21/)</kbd>

<kbd>[OnChange Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/jaLygLzo/26/)</kbd>